# What is object creation?

Tags: c#

I wrote some simple code.

```
class Customer
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;
}

class Worker
{
   public int Wage;
}

class Program
{
   Customer C = new Customer();
   C.FirstName = "James";
   C.LastName = "Cronin";
}
```

I know it's not going to print anything as there isn't any method. 
But I just couldn't understand the following code.

```
Customer C = new Customer();
```

I know `new Customer` is for making an instance of `Customer` object and `C` is an object reference variable that points to the location of that object in the heap.
And I get that `C` has to be of reference type to point to the location of object and that's why I use `Customer` type as the class is reference type.

But why does `C` have to `Customer` variable? 
I mean since `C` is just for pointing to the location of object why can't `C` be of any other class like `Worker` class?

Comment: Because C# is strongly typed.

Comment: Because that's not how statically typed languages work.  If you're looking to directly manipulate pointers to memory locations then C# probably isn't what you're looking for.  (Note also that the code you provided won't compile.  For multiple reasons.)

Comment: You can however create and instance of an object into any variable typed as a base class of your class. For instance if `Customer` inherited a `Person` class: `class Customer : Person { /* ... */ };`. You could instantiate that `Customer` into a `Person` variable: `Person p = new Customer();` since `Customer` is also of the type `Person`.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about trying to learn everything from the lowest level up, unless you are an experienced low-level coder trying C# for the first time. It's kind of like math, where you have to do it a bunch of times before you really get it.

Answer (score 3):

As already said its because c# is strongly typed <-- [What does strongly typed means in .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779804/what-does-strongly-typed-means-in-net-framework).

But here is a little mind experiment.
Just think about the size of the customer and of the worker in the memory.
Worker has one variable and customer has two so they "can't" be the same size in the memory.

If you want to get rid of this declaration

`Customer c = new Customer();`

you could easily say

`var c = new Customer();`

this wouldn't change a bit in the memory or the IL and I don't recommend it generally for the sace of readability(Sometimes its more readable) but if its your project and you are happy with it, do it.

Maybe something else to keep in mind: Say we have a generic list with Customers in it and you want to iterate through it, your program knows the size of the object and can simply jump from object to object without reading every object.

These examples are very simplified but I hope you get the point.
You can't put a liter of milk into an empty 500ml botte of orange juice without avoiding that somebody is confused

EDIT:
Since I am not an employee of Microsoft and I don't have insight in all the details of the CLR, I can't really say much about the details but I guess that its a lot like in java where much of the details are put into the IL representation of your program. So your class worker has a different size and different pointers in it to different variables of different sizes than the customer. So when the program is executed the program has to know where to point to and what size the object has, so that it knows where another object in the object is or where a method begins. I would guess you could write a whole book about this stuff and just scratch on the top of it. But having wrote all that it is much more complicated than:" Here is a pointer to an object and here is one so whats the difference ? " ;)

Comment: these are good points. I disagree a bit with you not recommending ever to use var though... I routinely use it to save some keystrokes, when constructing a new "Something". For example, instead of `ProcessSvcs.ProcessServiceNormalClient svc = new ProcessSvcs.ProcessServiceNormalClient();`, I can just say `var svc = new ProcessSvcs.ProcessServiceNormalClient();` and it's still perfectly clear what the object will be.

Comment: Okayyour argument is valid :) I'll change that :)

Answer (score 2):

An object is basically a block of memory that has been allocated and configured according to the blueprint.

The blueprint in your case is a `Customer` class, and memory allocation occurs when `Customer C = new Customer();` line is executed.

More reading on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110.aspx)

Comment: yeah the comparisson with the blueprint is nice to keep in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassB b = new ClassB()
        {
            PropclassA = new ClassA()
            {
                TestProp = 10,
            }
        };

        ClassB b1 = new ClassB();
        b1.PropclassA.TestProp = 100;
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    public int TestProp { get; set; }
}
class ClassB
{
    public ClassB()
    {
        PropclassA = new ClassA();
    }

    public ClassA PropclassA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: while you have attempted to answer. you provide no explanation. consider adding comments and explaining how your answer solves the OPs Question