# How to store objects in List or Dictionary (JS way)?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#
I want to store some simple objects in a associative array, JS like

```
var part["part1"] = {id:1, name:"part 1 ", posX:100, posY:200};
var part["part2"] = {id:2, name:"part 2 ", posX:300, posY:250};
```

and then retrieve that easily with

```
name = "part2"
print(part[name].x);
```

I had a look at: NameValueCollection, but it looks I can store simple values there only.

I tried with Collections and structures: which looks quite big and heavy just to store some simple values.

Is there a **better/quicker/simpler** way?

Comment: I think you can try to use `Dictionary<string,T>`

Comment: @yarek you can use `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, it allows you to access an internal object properties, unlike `Dictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

For example

```
var part = new Dictionary<string, object>();
part.Add("part1", new { id = 1, name = "part 1 ", posX = 100, posY = 200});
part.Add("part2", new { id = 2, name = "part 2 ", posX = 300, posY = 250});

var result = part["part1"];
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rw641f)

---

**Updated**

If you want to access the property in C#, you should declare [`Specify Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes). This is simply because, [C# is strong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779804/what-does-strongly-typed-means-in-net-framework) whereas  [`Javascript` is weak type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language)

As a result, you can see the sample below to more understand

```
public static void Main()
{
    var persons = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
    persons.Add("Phong", new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Phong"});
    persons.Add("Nguyen", new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Nguyen"});

    var result = persons["Phong"];
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + result.Id + " Name: " + result.Name);
        // Output: ID: 1 Name: Phong
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rw641f)

Comment: You can't access the properties of anonymous object in this example, make sense to use `dynamic`

Comment: Yes, I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Pavel Anikhouski. Basically, the OP just wants to know `How to store objects in List or Dictionary (JS way)?
`

Answer (score 2):

You can create class which will store all properties like `id`, `name`, `posX`, `posY`. To associate this class with `part` name you can use dictionary.

Structure will look like,

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int PosX {get; set;}
    public int PosY {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can create dictionary where key will be your string `part` name and value will be instance of `Location` class

```
Dictionary<string, Location> part = new Dictionary<string, Location>();
```

To store values in result,

```
  part.Add("part1", new Locataion(1, "part 1", 100, 200));
  part.Add("part2", new Locataion(2, "part 2", 300, 250));
```

To print value `Name` of part2, you can do

```
Console.WriteLine(part["part2"].Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

C# does not allow you the "freedom" you have in JavaScript. So, you should create a specific type for what the map will hold. I know, that is sometimes not comfortable.

Another approach is to leverage the NewtonSoft.JSON library ([JLinq section](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)), then use a `Dictionary<string, JObject>` to hold JSON "nodes":

```
string json = @"{
  'channel': {
    'title': 'James Newton-King',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com',
    'description': 'James Newton-King\'s blog.',
    'item': [
      {
        'title': 'Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex',
        'description': 'Announcing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and the source on CodePlex',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'CodePlex'
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'LINQ to JSON beta',
        'description': 'Announcing LINQ to JSON',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'LINQ'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}";

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

string rssTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["title"];
// James Newton-King

string itemTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
// Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex

JArray categories = (JArray)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["categories"];
// ["Json.NET", "CodePlex"]

IList<string> categoriesText = categories.Select(c => (string)c).ToList();
// Json.NET
// CodePlex
```