# Trying to access vars within Custom Unity Component Script

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, components

I've run into a situation where I'm trying to access variables stored within a script component.

There are about 8 actions that a player can do to an gameObject.
Users attach these action scripts to a gameObject which controls how Actions play out.

During gameplay I need to loop through the gameObject's components and match the selected Action to the attached component. I've successfully found the corresponding action script attached to the component, but I'm unable to then find variables contained within it....

```
        // LOOP THROUGH THISEL COMPONENTS
        var thisElComps=thisEl.GetComponents<Component>();

        for(var i=0; i<thisElComps.Length; i++){
            var thisComp=thisElComps[i].GetType();

            // IF COMPONENT MATCHES ACTIVE SELECTED ACTION
            if(activeVerb.name == thisComp.ToString()){
                print("found");
                // need to access settings inside component here!
                // if(thisComp.myVar){};
           
            // SELECTED ACTION COMPONENT NOT FOUND
            }else{
                
                print("not found");
            }
        }
```

Found and Not Found are printing correctly but everything I've tried I cannot seem to get access to the vars inside the component :/ Sorry for newbie question but am new to C# and coming from different language. Thanks

UPDATE: For examples sake here is an attached component script.

```
public class ActionClassName: MonoBehaviour {
    public string myVar;   
}
```

thisComp.myVar; (error: there is no definition of myVar)

print(thisElComps[i] is Component);
returns true

UPDATE:

```
typeName="myAction";

var myComp=thisEl.GetComponent("myAction");
```

found!

```
var myComp=thisEl.GetComponent(System.Type.GetType(typeName));
```

error: type cannot be null

Comment: well you havent shared a relevant component example, but it would never be thisComp.myvar you need to get thisElComps[i].myvar probably type casted as you got type component not the specific type. as normally you do getcomponent<mytype> to get access to that specific thing and its variables

Comment: thisComp is pointing to thisElComps[i].... I'm coming from JS so the strict vars is driving me nuts. My type needs to be a var and I'm not sure how to cast it in this manner.

Comment: Just updated a sample component script. There would be several acting as different "actions" on the item they are attached to. While I'm able to detect if whatever is attached, I can't grab myVar inside of it.

Comment: Base types do not inherit variables from classes that extend it.  You would need to cast the Component to the specific type that declared the variable.  eg. `(MyDerivedComponent)thisElComps[i];`

Comment: actually this|Comp is .getType so actualy its not pointing to the array but the type of the object that was in the array

Comment: Thanks BugFinder - just saw that as well, but pulling it directly off thisElComps[i].myVar has the same error - Component does not contain a definition for....

Comment: EDIT- don't think myderivedcomponent is what I'm looking for since I'm only looking to reference an existing component's settings

Answer (score 0):

C# is not like Javascript! [C# is strongly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779804/what-does-strongly-typed-means-in-net-framework) meaning in order to access your `myVar` you definitely need a reference of type `whatever` (o derived from that)

You cast and check for `Component` which doesn't have/know a `myVar`.

Actually why even go through all components if you only are interested in a specific type at all?

```
var thisElComps = thisEl.GetComponents<whatever>();

foreach(var thisComp in thisElComps)
{
    if(activeVerb.name == thisComp.ToString())
    {
        print("found");
        if(thisComp.myVar)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You could also throw in some `break`  onl interested in the first match or use [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault).

**HOWEVER*, further note that `thisComp.ToString()` returns the same as `thisComp.name` which returns the same as `thisComp.gameObject.name` which equals `thisEl.name`

=> The check will always either pass or fail for **all** items in `thisElComps` at the same time

If you rather wanted to find component of a specific type via string once again you can simply us the stringed overload and do

```
var theComp = thisEl.GetComponent(activVerb.name) as whatever;
if(theComp)
{
    print("found");
    print(theComp.myVar);
}
else
{
    print("not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand it is strongly typed and that is the problem. The whatever is a reference to one of many scripts that can be attached to the component. I'm searching for that script based on the activeVerb variable for a match. So... your answer with var thisElComps = thisEl.GetComponents<whatever>(); doesn't help since the type should be a variable as requested in the post. After more research I believe generics is what I'm looking for? Your last attempt with var theComp = thisEl.GetComponent(activVerb.name) as whatever; also won't work since whatever, again, is a var

Comment: @makeITwork well my assumption was that all the components you are looking for actually derive from `whatever` as the variable you are looking for is only implemented in `whatever` ... otherwise we would need more information about what you actually are trying to achieve by that ... maybe a common interface is what you rather want to use (which can be passed to `GetComponent(s)` as well)? ... I think your use case is not fully clear yet

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - I've updated the question again. Each action that can happen is stored in a separate script file. Those files are attached as components to an obj. I just need to compare the activeVerb variable against the name of the component and access the properties within the component. It seems like the main hurdle I'm actually running into is getting the Type when all I have is the string value. GetType is only returning null when the string is correct

Comment: @makeITwork I think it would really help to have more than only one example of you classes ... I still don't really understand what exactly you are trying to (or thinking to) achieve by that ... in your latest attempt e.g. the passed string should no be `myAction` but rather `ActionClassName` ... but in general going string based there looks like a design flaw ... what speaks against a strong typed approach from the beginning? Your question still feels like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;)

Comment: I've been going in circles trying to find a way to do this strong typed but this is more for backend flexibility than anything and cannot. I've rewritten things 3 times but always come back to having the type in string format. The ActionClassName is just a generalized example since there are going to be multiple actions in different scripts. These get attached to a GO. When an event happens - I check which action is attached and access the properties...

Comment: I know and understand how frustrating things can be. Still though, you explain what you are trying to do - but not what you are trying to achieve by that. Of course there are ways (like using Reflection etc) to overcome / workaround strong typing in `c#` and go `string`-based .. but that is expensive, slow, error prone and hard to maintain as it takes away all the advantage of being strong typed and get errors on compile time rather than eventually if ever on run time. Sure you can **get** the according component by `string` using the correct type name - still you only get it as `Component`

Comment: So you would still have to implement a type check and react to each and every type differently - e.g. `switch(theComp){ case SomeActionClass someAction: /*do something*/ break; }` etc

Comment: I think you should take a step back and ask yourself: Is it always the same property you need to access? -> Your answer would be rather use a common base class/interface. Otherwise **Why do you need to get the properties?** -> maybe once again you could rather have a common interface / base class and rather expose a method like `ExecuteAction` and pass all required information in as parameter so going pretty much the other way round. The action wouldn't need to expose any data but would simply do whatever it is supposed to

Comment: That is actually the approach I'm jumping into now. Wasn't what I wanted since it essentially crams all of the action code into a single script and I then end up having to do a bunch of editor customization to split up the different actions. It just seems quite silly that c# doesn't have the flexibility to use a variable to pull components like this

Comment: well as said most probably because your entire approach architecture is simply not how you would do things in c# ... even in Javascript you would need beforehand with what type of action you are dealing with in order to access the correct fields otherwise you get `undefined` .. so again really not yet clear what you are trying to do or why .. there might be better approaches but for that we need to know first what the higher goal is here exactly ... for instance why do you get the desired type as a string in the first place? And why are all those actions components at all?

Comment: No, in JS I could pull all of the user-defined actions into an array, obj etc then use those variables to reference pretty much anything I wanted or make other variables based off of those names. Here, activeVerb is the user-defined actions list that has been pulled into an array and is the currently selected one. The end goal would have been to have users attach what action script(s) they want to use to the gameobject.

Comment: @makeITwork what you still can do .. I just don't understand why it has to be string based ... why not use the actual component types? Or as said why don't those actions have a common interface you can simply use .. etc